# FFMPEG image not updating

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, video-streaming, video-encoding

**THE INPUT FILES**

1. An overlay image that has is being updated every 5 seconds by a Python script
2. A small MP4 file that will be looped by a concat input
3. An MP3 file as audio source

**THE COMMAND (UPDATED)**

This is the command I'm currently using to combine and stream the inputs.

```
ffmpeg -re -i music.mp3 -f concat -i videoincludes.txt
-r 1 -loop 1 -f image2 -i overlay.png
-c:v libx264 -c:a aac -shortest -crf 23 -pix_fmt yuv420p
-maxrate 2500k -bufsize 2500k -preset ultrafast -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 2000k -b:a 192k -ar 44100
-filter_complex "[1:v][2:v] overlay=0:0" -map 0:a -strict -2
-f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/{key}
```

Als tried using `-framerate 1` instead of `-r 1`

**THE ISSUE**

So the issue is that the image doesn't always update. Sometimes it does update every couple seconds at the start but it stops updating after 10-20 seconds without any difference in log output and sometimes it just doesn't update.

I can however confirm that the image is being updated by the Python script but FFmpeg is just not picking this up.

I read setting the input format of the image to `image2` should allow it to update so I am not sure what is wrong or what I can do to improve it.

Comment: Not on a comp where I can test right now, but try changing `-r 1` to `-framerate 1` and add `-re` alongside it.

Comment: tried both flags but neither seem fix the issue :(

Comment: @Mulvya so I have done a little bit of testing and it seems the issue is that the image file isn't different enough from the previous one to trigger ffmpeg to update the file input, any idea on this?

Comment: I'll test it here.

Answer (score -1):

I'm working on the same task, and finally, I think, I found the answer.
Because streams different from each other we must reset their timestamps with `setpts=PTS-STARTPTS` to have them begin in the same zero timestamp . And, also, try to use `image2pipe` instead of `image2`.

This is your code with timestamp reset:

```
ffmpeg -re -i music.mp3 -f concat -i videoincludes.txt
-r 1 -loop 1 -f image2pipe -i overlay.png
-c:v libx264 -c:a aac -shortest -crf 23 -pix_fmt yuv420p
-maxrate 2500k -bufsize 2500k -preset ultrafast -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 2000k -b:a 192k -ar 44100
-filter_complex "[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[out_main]; [2:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[out_overlay]; [out_main][out_overlay]overlay=0:0" -map 0:a -strict -2
-f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/{key}
```

p.s and I think, there is no need in `-r` or `-framerate` anymore